# Function is undefined althoug it is declared right before

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a ToDo List App I am creating to learn React Native. When I try to pass a clickhandler to the child item, it says that the clickhandler-function is undefined.

Here is the relevant code.

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props)

  this.handleTodoPress = this.handleTodoPress.bind(this)
}
handleTodoPress (event) {
  console.warn('Press handled')
}
renderItem ({section, item}) {
  return <TodoItem onItemPress={this.handleTodoPress} title={item.title} description={item.description} completed={item.completed} />
}
```

If I log `handleTodoPress` in `renderItem` it shows up as undefined. Why is that?

Comment: how are you calling to `renderItem`?

Comment: You need to bind `renderItem` function too or use arrow function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few ways you can fix this like putting `renderItem` in the constructor just like `handleTodoPress` or you can use a property initializer:

```
renderItem  = ({section, item}) => {
  return <TodoItem onItemPress={this.handleTodoPress} title={item.title} description={item.description} completed={item.completed} />
}
```

Now `this` will point to the component and allow you to use `this.handleTodoPress`